# Generating a CSV file to be imported into Excel, what should I use for a newline character?

Tags: winforms, csv

Creating a CSV file in a winforms application, it is to be improted into Excel.

The file output looks like:

"header1", "header2", "header3",
1,2,3,
4,5,6

**What should I use to signify a newline character when generating the CSV file?**

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest using [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 4108](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)

> While there are various specifications and implementations for the
>      CSV format (for ex. [4], [5], [6] and [7]), there is no formal
>      specification in existence, which allows for a wide variety of
>      interpretations of CSV files.  This section documents the format that
>      seems to be followed by most implementations:
>
> 1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
>         break (CRLF).  For example:
>
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>         zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF

Answer (score 0):

use \r\n although it will work with just \n

Answer (score 0):

I generally stick with "\n" - because it will be "correct" for the platform on which it is used.